# Return asynchronous result from AJAX called from dynamically loaded page

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, asynchronous, jquery-load

Currently I have a page which I have loaded using jQuery as follows:

```
$('#content').load('mypage.html');
```

This is called inside `site.js`. Inside the loaded page, I have loaded a script which I am trying to return an asynchronous result from, so it does not freeze.

The page is as follows:

```
<div id="mycontent"></div>

<script type="text/javascript" src="js/getmycontent.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(function() {
        $('body').ajaxComplete(function() {

            var ids = {
                "h1": 123,
                "h2": 12345
            };

            //$('.loader-wrapper').show();

            // Iterate over id numbers
            $.each(ids, function(k, v) {
                var mylist;

                var call = getMyList(v).done(function(r) {
                    if(r) {
                        mylist = r.mylist;
                    } else {
                        mylist = null;
                    }
                }).fail(function(x) {
                    alert(x);
                });

                console.log(mylist);

            });

            //$('.loader-wrapper').hide();
        });
    });
</script>
```

Here is the `getmycontent.js`:

```
function getMyList(id) {
    var url = 'https://api.myurl.org/v1/lists/' + id;
    return $.ajax({
        url: url,
        type: 'get',
        dataType: 'json'
    });
}
```

The console doesn't log anything when I have the `ajaxComplete` function on `body`, but I was doing some reading and this is what someone suggested I do for dynamically loaded pages.

When I remove the `ajaxComplete` call, I get this in the console:

```
send @ jquery.min.js:2
ajax @ jquery.min.js:2
w._evalUrl @ jquery.min.js:2
Re @ jquery.min.js:2
append @ jquery.min.js:2
(anonymous) @ jquery.min.js:2
z @ jquery.min.js:2
html @ jquery.min.js:2
(anonymous) @ jquery.min.js:2
u @ jquery.min.js:2
fireWith @ jquery.min.js:2
k @ jquery.min.js:2
(anonymous) @ jquery.min.js:2
load (async)
send @ jquery.min.js:2
ajax @ jquery.min.js:2
w.fn.load @ jquery.min.js:2
(anonymous) @ site.js:20
dispatch @ jquery.min.js:2
y.handle @ jquery.min.js:2
6VM400:34 undefined
```

This is VM400 from the console:

```
$(function() {
        $('body').ajaxComplete(function() {

            var ids = {
                "h1": 123,
                "h2": 12345
            };

            //$('.loader-wrapper').show();

            // Iterate over id numbers
            $.each(ids, function(k, v) {
                var mylist;

                var call = getMyList(v).done(function(r) {
                    if(r) {
                        mylist = r.mylist;
                    } else {
                        mylist = null;
                    }
                }).fail(function(x) {
                    alert(x);
                });

                console.log(mylist);

            });

            //$('.loader-wrapper').hide();
        });
    });
```

Answer (score 1):

This might be because of the following reason:

> #### Additional Notes:
>
> - As of jQuery 1.9, all the handlers for the [jQuery global Ajax events](https://api.jquery.com/category/ajax/global-ajax-event-handlers/), including those added with the `.ajaxComplete()` method, *must* be attached to `document`.
> - If [`$.ajax()`](https://api.jquery.com/jQuery.Ajax/) or [`$.ajaxSetup()`](https://api.jquery.com/jQuery.ajaxSetup/) is called with the `global` option set to `false`, the `.ajaxComplete()` method will not fire.

For more info about `$.ajaxComplete()` have a look at the [documentation](https://api.jquery.com/ajaxComplete/).

Answer (score -1):

The issue has been resolved by changing the `page.html` and `getmycontent.js` files respectively. Using a callback allowed me to handle the data once it has been retrieved. See [ASync Callback Promise](https://medium.com/front-end-weekly/ajax-async-callback-promise-e98f8074ebd7).

`page.html`:

```
<div id="mycontent"></div>

<script type="text/javascript" src="js/getmycontent.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
    function callback(result) { console.log(result) }

    $(function() {
            var ids = {
                "h1": 123,
                "h2": 12345
            };

            //$('.loader-wrapper').show();

            // Iterate over id numbers
            $.each(ids, function(k, v) {
                var call = getMyList(v, callback);
            });
    });
</script>
```

`getmycontent.js`:

```
function getMyList(id, callback) {
    var url = 'https://api.myurl.org/v1/lists/' + id;
    $.ajax({
        url: url,
        type: 'get',
        dataType: 'json',
        async: true,
        success: callback
    });
}
```

Comment: Although I'm glad the issue is resolved, this answer changes the functionality of the original answer. Here you simply execute some code after the DOM is ready loading. Whereas in the question you set a global ajaxComplete handler that executes after every completed [`$.ajax()`](https://api.jquery.com/jQuery.Ajax/) request. That might also be the reason that your own answer got down voted.

Comment: @JohanWentholt I do state in my original answer, that my use of `ajaxComplete` was my attempt at a fix, and I do state that the end result (error) is a result of me not using `ajaxComplete`.

Comment: That wasn't very clear to me from reading the question. In that case you might want to formulate your question more clearly in the future. A good place to start is always 1. Describe what the code should do. 2. If any, describe the input and/or output. 3. Provide an example. Have a look at the [Help Center - How do I ask a good question?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) for more details about good questions.

Comment: The sentence *"This is called inside `site.js`. Inside the loaded page, I have loaded a script which I am trying to return an asynchronous result from, so it does not freeze."* has a few issues. 1. Return from what to where? 2. What freezes? I think you get the point.